# Dialog Behavior is wearied. while adding gridview

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, android-alertdialog

I want to show images in dialog with the help of grid View. it is working fine but i am having a little problem with opening of Dialog. as you can see in screenshot. As i open dialog it opns but very small.

[image]

But after scrolling down up to 2 or 3 items it automatically switch to bigger size. I don't understand why?

[image]

**What i have Tried so far**

code for showing dialog

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_select_layout, null);
        final GridView grid = (GridView) layout
                .findViewById(R.id.select_gridview);
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ArtFun.this);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(grid);
        
        grid.setAdapter(new ImagesAdapter(ArtFun.this));
        grid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "position = "+ position, 1).show();
                
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
```

image_select_layout.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/select_gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"      
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"       
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"    
    android:gravity="center" 
    android:background="@drawable/imageselect_bg"    
/>
```

My ImageAdapter is this

```
public class ImagesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater gridInflater;
    private final int BACKGROUND_IDS[] = new int[] { R.drawable.image_004,
            R.drawable.image_005, R.drawable.img, R.drawable.image_004,
            R.drawable.image_005, R.drawable.img};
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;

    public ImagesAdapter(Context context){
    
        gridInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return BACKGROUND_IDS.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return BACKGROUND_IDS[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = gridInflater.inflate(R.layout.image_adapter_layout, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.adapter_view);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        DisplayImageOptions option = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.image_005)
        .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.image_005).cacheOnDisc(false)
        .cacheInMemory(false).displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(500))
        .build();
        
        String uri = "drawable://" + BACKGROUND_IDS[position];
        
        imageLoader.displayImage(uri, holder.img, option);

        return convertView;
    }

     static class ViewHolder {
            ImageView img;
        }
}
```

Image_adapter_layout.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/adapter_view"
    android:layout_width="100dip"
    android:layout_height="100dip"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

**What i want now**

I want to show dialog every time like showing in 2nd screenshot. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this myself.. as the images i was display were larger in size..  i just replace them with their thumbnails. and it works.. i don't really know why the dialog was initially too small.. but after changing images it works for me.

If any one knows the reason for this please share thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can set custom width and height for your dialog like this.

```
dialog.getWindow().setLayout(width, height);
```